# Binding generator (like SWIG) that handles C-style callbacks?

Tags: binding, swig

I recently wrote a binding for a C library using SWIG.  While a good deal of it was straight forward and used only basic SWIG functionality, I ran into trouble when I needed to support one function which took a C callback as an argument, which is not supported for SWIG.  I solved this by writing Python-specific code to provide a custom callback in which I called the Python 'eval' function to evaluate a supplied Callable.

While this worked nicely, it was unfortunate for me.. I had been hoping to use SWIG to take advantage of its support for tens of languages, but now I'm stuck having to figure out callbacks in every single language I wish to support.  This makes my binding work magnitudes less useful, as I now have to solve the same problem many times, manually--the opposite of the point of using SWIG.

Are there any tool like SWIG that *also* handles C callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit rounadabout but if you recompile the C project in C++ or create a C++ extension, then you can take advantage of virtual function overloading.

Most SWIG language module have support for [directors](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn33) which allow a class in the target language to derive from a class in the C++ library. This way any overridden virtual function act as a callback.